# Are Apple's simulated iOS devices' Safari apps exactly the same as real devices for testing offline storage?

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, mobile-safari

I want to test an offline web app and using HTML5 storage, in particular testing:

1. Application cache
2. WebSQL
3. LocalStorage

Do the simulators have exactly the same limits and implementations as Safari on a real iOS device?

For example, will this code work exactly the same in giving user prompts and limits as on a real iPad?

```
db.transaction(function onTransaction(t) {
  t.executeSql('INSERT INTO entries (name, size, date, payload) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)', data,
  function onExecuteSqlCallback(t, results) {
...
  },
  function onExecuteSqlError(t, e) {
// Returning true to rollback, false to continue the transaction;
return false;
  });
},
function onTransactionError(sqlError) {
  //Over quota
  if (sqlError.code === sqlError.QUOTA_ERR) {
        ... 
  }
},
function onTransactionSuccess() {
  ...
});
```

Comment: The simulator is meant as a sanity tool, not as a full testing tool. You should always be testing on an actual device as well as the simulator. The simulator runs on Mac OS APIs, has a different architecture, and runs off of your computers RAM (meaning performance is better). It might work, but it might also have sharp edges.

Comment: @Msencenb so it's not reliable for testing offline web apps in safari?

Comment: You can certainly try it and compare against a real device, it might work flawlessly. I just caution against using the simulator as your main testing device.

Comment: @Msencenb that used to be more true in the past.  As of iOS 7, the only OS X APIs used in the iOS Simulator Runtime were libSystem APIs.  As of iOS 8, that has been further slimmed to just the libsystem_kernel, libsystem_platform, and libsystem_pthread children of libSystem.  For things a a high level, like WebKit, the Simulator should be a very good approximation for device behavior.  There is some functionality that may not be available (eg: cellular, push, etc) and obviously hardware characteristics are different as well.